# How to parse a string into a func to use at runtime?

Tags: c#

How can I allow a user to enter a string into a winforms application and then use reflection to parse that string which can be executed at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: Execute what? a method in a class? a mathematical expression? more detail on what you want to execute.

Comment: Sorry. A method in a class which takes a func as a parameter.

Comment: Reflection does not parse strings. A compiler (parser) does. You might consider using `IronPython`, Dynamic LINQ, or an expression parsing library, depending on the nature of the problem.

Comment: I've done this with building assembly with class from string (can't find source anymore where i found it). I/O was through hashtables. Anyway - in general this is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security holes galore, I think, unless you do this with the utmost care! If you really want to do this however, you'll want to look into using the [CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). Since C# is not (yet) a [dynamic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_language), it does not have an `eval` feature, and dynamically compiling assemblies with the CodeDOM is the closest you'll get.

For an example, see my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments/826435#826435), which uses `CSharpCodeProvider` along with the CodeDOM to achieve the goal. Beware though, if you want to make your app even reasonably secure, you'll want to run the code with its own AppDomain, and possibly its own process (with some form of IPC).

Comment: "Dynamic language" (like C# 4.0) usually means "dynamically typed language." It doesn't have much to do with `eval`.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I have to disagree with that. 'Dynamic language' is a very different term to 'dynamically typed language'. See the wikipedia article for clarification: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_language

Comment: Note that 'eval' is listed as the first feature of a dynamic language. :) Anyway, I've added the wiki link in my post to clarify things.

Comment: Although you are generally right about possible security holes there are enough scenarios where his idea is legit. He might be coding a development tool of some sort where the users are developers, too. Also it makes sense to add scripting to an application in order for users to be able to extend its functionality.

Comment: I agree about the broad definition of dynamic language. My comment specifically applies to C# 4.0 (which might be inferred from "not yet"), which is a dynamically typed language, but doesn't have dynamic compilation. Anyway, I just wanted to point out that `eval` and dynamic typing are orthogonal and not necessarily required for each other.

Comment: @Robert: Yeah, was just trying to stress how careful he must be. :) I know this from experience in the area.

Comment: @Mehrdad: My "not yet" refers to C# not yet having the compiler-as-a-service feature, which is rumoured for .NET 5.0/C# 5.0. Indeed, dynamic languages (including `eval`) and dynamic typing are largely orthogonal, though the first *tends* to imply the latter.

Comment: Thanks for this guys. This is not a definate feature, but was something which is useful and being considered for an internal application.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use reflection to parse a string.

You could use the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class to compile the string (assuming it contains C#) into a temporary assembly. From that you can create objects, locate methods on them and execute them.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508213/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-execute-a-string-in-net-similar-to-eval-in-java) might give you some hints.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!381.entry) might help you.

TODO list extracted from there:

> 1. Transform and wrap user defined method/function body with appropriate method, class, namespace, etc. declarations using the CodeDom (so to get the ready to compile sources either into memory or physical file)
> 2. Compile the resulting Dom into the assembly (I'll be using physical files)
> 3. Create a separate application domain and load compiled assembly into it.
> 4. Extract the generated method from the loaded assembly and invoke it against the execution context (in this case it will be a Window)
> 5. Free resources, unload second application domain and perform a temporary files cleanup.

P.s. - DON'T DO IT!