# How to Run string value as a function?

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically)

I have one string in csharp

```
string li_id = "Frm_menu_purchase_order.visible=false;";
```

Now i wanna execute this string value as a c sharp statement

just like

```
Frm_menu_purchase_order.visible=false;
```

Comment: this can be usefull.. or may be not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508213/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-execute-a-string-in-net-similar-to-eval-in-jav

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

You can use the `Evaluator` class found on Codeproject.

Check out [Evaluate C# Code (Eval Function)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx)

The class uses `CodeDom` do make this possible. But i suggest you are looking for another solution instead of using the `Evaluator`. But it works!

#### More Information

- [MSDN - System.CodeDom Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx)
- [Codeplex - Evaluate C# Code (Eval Function)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx)

Comment: Your link is invalid (gives `The resource cannot be found` error)

Comment: Sorry, link is fixed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use Reflection, please see below:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/evalcscode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CodeDom: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/CodeDomDelegates.aspx