# C# taking arguments & declaring at runtime from text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file with the following:

```
int A = 5 ;
string str = "tempstring" ;
str DosomeMethod 15 16 20 22 ;
```

When reading the text file thru my program, I want to declare `int A = 5` & `string str = "tempstring"` at runtime.

It can be like

```
string[] st = freader.readline().split(' ');
if (st[0]=="int")
    {
      str[0] str[1] = str[4];
    }
```

I know that the above is the wrong syntax but I want to do something like this with some reference.

Can anybody help without using irony .net?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/508213/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-execute-a-string-in-net-similar-to-eval-in-jav

Comment: you can accomplish this sort of feature using Expression Trees

Comment: What about using dynamic? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Comment: As others have said, what you're asking for is pretty advanced stuff.  Perhaps explain why you're trying to do this - there may be a better approach.

Comment: I am developing prorgamme for a machine which will work with PLC. Now my application is interacting with PLC & should call around 130 text files as instructions into programme at runtime based upon decision made by PLC. writing 130-150 individual functions are difficult.

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively advanced material.
You can't really do as you said. C# is a `strongly-typed` language.
Although, you may seek to one of these solutions:

- [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) - a script language which uses .NET.
- C#'s [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword.
- [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- [Dynamically compiling C# code within application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6492/A-tool-for-dynamic-compile-and-run-of-C-or-VB-NET)
- Or, if you seek a quick solution, you may set these variables (`string temp` and so on) within your code, then put values into them according to the string.